# How can I get data for a specific element, id in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-templates

views.py

```
from datetime import datetime

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from django.apps import apps
from django.contrib import messages
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.contrib.auth.views import LoginView, LogoutView
from django.db import transaction
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect, JsonResponse
from django.shortcuts import redirect, render
from django.urls import reverse, reverse_lazy
from django.utils.decorators import method_decorator
from django.views import View
from django.views.generic import (
    CreateView,
    DetailView,
    ListView,
    TemplateView,
    UpdateView,
)


@method_decorator(login_required(login_url=reverse_lazy("core:login")), name="dispatch")
class HomePageView(TemplateView):
    template_name = "home.html"

    def get_queryset(self):
        model_names = [
            model.__name__ for model in apps.get_app_config("core").get_models()
        ]

        return model_names

    @method_decorator(login_required)
    def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super(HomePageView, self).dispatch(*args, **kwargs)

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context["models_list"] = self.get_queryset()
        return context


class LoginView(LoginView):
    template_name = "login.html"

    def form_valid(self, form):
        messages.info(
            self.request, f"You are now logged in as {form.cleaned_data['username']}"
        )
        return super().form_valid(form)

    def form_invalid(self, form):
        messages.error(self.request, "Invalid username or password.")
        return super().form_invalid(form)


class LogoutView(LogoutView):
    next_page = reverse_lazy("core:home")
    template_name = "logout.html"


class ModelDetailsView(DetailView):
    template_name = "list_datas.html"
    context_object_name = "model_data"

    def get_object(self, queryset=None):
        model_name = self.kwargs["model_name"]
        Model = apps.get_model("core", model_name)
        return Model.objects.filter(is_active=True)

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        model_name = self.kwargs["model_name"]
        Model = apps.get_model("core", model_name)

        instances = Model.objects.filter(is_active=True)

        field_names = [
            field.name
            for field in Model._meta.get_fields()
            if field.name
            not in [
                "is_active",
                "created_by",
                "last_modified_by",
                "last_modified_on",
                "created_on",
            ]
        ]
        field_names_info_modal = [
            field.name
            for field in Model._meta.get_fields()
            if field.name
            in [
                "id",
                "created_by",
                "last_modified_by",
                "last_modified_on",
                "created_on",
            ]
        ]

        data = []
        data_for_info_modal = []
        for instance in instances:
            instance_data = [
                getattr(instance, field_name) for field_name in field_names
            ]
            data.append(instance_data)
            instance_data_for_info_modal = [
                getattr(instance, field_name) for field_name in field_names_info_modal
            ]
            data_for_info_modal.append(instance_data_for_info_modal)

        context["field_names"] = field_names
        context["model_data"] = data
        context["model_data_for_info_modal"] = data_for_info_modal
        context["model_name"] = model_name
        context["export_url"] = reverse(
            "core:export_excel", kwargs={"model_name": model_name}
        )
        return context

    def export_to_excel(self, model_name):
        Model = apps.get_model("core", model_name)
        instances = Model.objects.filter(is_active=True)

        # Get field names
        field_names = [
            field.name
            for field in Model._meta.get_fields()
            if field.name
            not in [
                "is_active",
                "created_by",
                "last_modified_by",
                "last_modified_on",
                "created_on",
            ]
        ]

        # Get data
        data = []
        for instance in instances:
            instance_data = [
                getattr(instance, field_name) for field_name in field_names
            ]
            data.append(instance_data)

        # Create a DataFrame
        df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=field_names)

        # Create response
        response = HttpResponse(content_type="application/ms-excel")
        response[
            "Content-Disposition"
        ] = f'attachment; filename="{model_name}_datas.xlsx"'

        # Write DataFrame to Excel
        df.to_excel(response, index=False)

        return response

    @method_decorator(login_required)
    def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super(ModelDetailsView, self).dispatch(*args, **kwargs)


class ExportExcelView(View):
    def get(self, request, model_name):
        model_details_view = ModelDetailsView()
        return model_details_view.export_to_excel(model_name)

    @method_decorator(login_required)
    def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super(ExportExcelView, self).dispatch(*args, **kwargs)


class DeleteSelectedModelsView(View):
    def post(self, request, model_name):
        selected_items = request.POST.getlist("selected_items")

        if selected_items:
            Model = apps.get_model("core", model_name)

            selected_items = [int(item) for item in selected_items]

            with transaction.atomic():
                Model.objects.filter(pk__in=selected_items).update(is_active=False)

            messages.success(request, "Selected items have been deleted successfully.")

        return HttpResponseRedirect(
            reverse_lazy("core:model_details", kwargs={"model_name": model_name})
        )

    @method_decorator(login_required)
    def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super(DeleteSelectedModelsView, self).dispatch(*args, **kwargs)


class UpdateModelView(UpdateView):
    template_name = "update.html"
    model = None
    fields = "__all__"

    def get_object(self, queryset=None):
        model_name = self.kwargs["model_name"]
        Model = apps.get_model("core", model_name)
        return Model.objects.get(pk=self.kwargs["pk"])

    def get_success_url(self):
        model_name = self.kwargs["model_name"]
        return reverse_lazy("core:model_details", kwargs={"model_name": model_name})

    @method_decorator(login_required)
    def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super(UpdateModelView, self).dispatch(*args, **kwargs)
```

list_details.html

```
{% extends "partials/_base.html" %}
{% block title %}{{ model_name }}{% endblock title %}
{% block content %}
    <div class="mt-5">
        <h1 class="text-center">{{ model_name }}</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="container mt-5">
        <div class="d-flex">
            <form method="post" action="{% url 'core:delete_selected_models' model_name=model_name %}">
                {% csrf_token %}
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger mb-3" style="background-color: white;">
                    <i class="fa fa-solid fa-trash fa-lg" style="color: red;"></i>
                </button>
                <a href="{% url 'core:export_excel' model_name=model_name %}">
                    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="2em" viewBox="0 0 384 512" style="fill: green">
                        <path d="M64 0C28.7 0 0 28.7 0 64V448c0 35.3 28.7 64 64 64H320c35.3 0 64-28.7 64-64V160H256c-17.7 0-32-14.3-32-32V0H64zM256 0V128H384L256 0zM155.7 250.2L192 302.1l36.3-51.9c7.6-10.9 22.6-13.5 33.4-5.9s13.5 22.6 5.9 33.4L221.3 344l46.4 66.2c7.6 10.9 5 25.8-5.9 33.4s-25.8 5-33.4-5.9L192 385.8l-36.3 51.9c-7.6 10.9-22.6 13.5-33.4 5.9s-13.5-22.6-5.9-33.4L162.7 344l-46.4-66.2c-7.6-10.9-5-25.8 5.9-33.4s25.8-5 33.4 5.9z"/>
                    </svg>
                </a>
            </div>
            <table class="table table-light">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th></th> <!-- Checkbox -->
                        {% for field_name in field_names %}
                            <th>{{ field_name }}</th>
                        {% endfor %}
                        <th></th> <!-- Update -->
                        <th></th> <!-- Info -->

                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    {% for instance_data in model_data %}
                        <tr>
                            <td><input type="checkbox" name="selected_items" value="{{ instance_data.0 }}"></td>
                            {% for value in instance_data %}
                                <td>{{ value }}</td>
                            {% endfor %}
                            <td>
                                <td><a href="{% url 'core:update_model' model_name=model_name pk=instance_data.0 %}"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="1.25em" viewBox="0 0 512 512"><style>svg{fill:#345184}</style><path d="M471.6 21.7c-21.9-21.9-57.3-21.9-79.2 0L362.3 51.7l97.9 97.9 30.1-30.1c21.9-21.9 21.9-57.3 0-79.2L471.6 21.7zm-299.2 220c-6.1 6.1-10.8 13.6-13.5 21.9l-29.6 88.8c-2.9 8.6-.6 18.1 5.8 24.6s15.9 8.7 24.6 5.8l88.8-29.6c8.2-2.7 15.7-7.4 21.9-13.5L437.7 172.3 339.7 74.3 172.4 241.7zM96 64C43 64 0 107 0 160V416c0 53 43 96 96 96H352c53 0 96-43 96-96V320c0-17.7-14.3-32-32-32s-32 14.3-32 32v96c0 17.7-14.3 32-32 32H96c-17.7 0-32-14.3-32-32V160c0-17.7 14.3-32 32-32h96c17.7 0 32-14.3 32-32s-14.3-32-32-32H96z"/></svg></a></td>
                            </td>
                            <td data-id="{{ instance_data.0 }}">
                                <i data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal" class="fa fa-solid fa-info" style="cursor: pointer;"></i>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    {% endfor %}
                </tbody>
            </table>
            <!-- Modal -->
            <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        {% for info_datas in model_data_for_info_modal %}
                        <tr>
                            {{ info_datas.0 }}
                        </tr>
                        {% endfor %}
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>       
        
{% endblock %}
```

If I press the info button next to any element in the table, I want the info_datas.0 value of that element to appear in the modal.
Is there anyone who can help?

[image]
[image]
As you can see, the info_datas.0 value of all elements is now displayed. However, I want to see just one value. If I press info near the id=1 element I need to see 1.

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Emphasis on minimal.